# Can't set subfolder path in Workbooks VB Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I've two excel vba workbooks. First, 'Formini1.xlsm' as source file. Second one, 'Tampil1.xlsm' as target file. Both files located in different folders. I've a task to connect source file into target file. Here's the location of each file:

- Target file: "C://project/tampil1.xlsm"
- Source file: "C://project/database/formini1.xlsm"

Here's the code (in same folder):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim RangeKriteria As Range, RangeCopyTo As Range, RangeTabel As Range

Set RangeTabel = Workbooks("formini1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet3").[A1].CurrentRegion
Set RangeCopyTo = Workbooks("tampil1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2").[L1]
Set RangeKriteria = Workbooks("tampil1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2").[A1:I10]


With Workbooks("tampil1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Cells.Clear
    .[A1:I1].Value = Workbooks("formini1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet3").[A1:I1].Value
    .[A2].Value = "*" & TextBox1.Value
    .[B3].Value = "*" & TextBox1.Value
    RangeTabel.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=RangeKriteria _
    , CopyToRange:=RangeCopyTo, _
        Unique:=False
End With    
End Sub
```

But the problem, I must make those files in different folder, so I change RangeTabel into this code:

```
Set RangeTabel = Workbooks("C://project/database/formini1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet3").[A1].CurrentRegion
```

But it said error. I don't know why. Is there any idea so I could make subfolder path on Workbooks?

Thanks a lot

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: save the workbooks as varaibles first and then refer to them

Comment: @QHarr Run-time error "9": subscript of out range.

Comment: I think as per my comment save them as workbook variables and then refer to these workbook variables. Note they must be open to use the workbooks collection. You can't have the filepath as part of the string inside of the workbooks().

Comment: @QHarr could you show me, how the code? Im so sorry, I get your mind, but I can't implement it.

Comment: Are you using a mac?

Comment: If you are working in Windows, try **BACK-SLASH**, so you should have: `Set RangeTabel = Workbooks("C:\project\database\formini1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet3").[A1].CurrentRegion`.

Comment: @FDavidov It's error sir. I try used it, but it said 'subscript out of range'

Comment: That's a different error. Your previous was caused by the fact that you wrongly defined the path (using `/` instead of '\'). The new error is caused by the fact that you are addressing something that does not exist (wild guess, check `.[A1].CurrentRegion`; I thing that `[A1]` is not a legal cell specification).

Answer (score 0):

If the workbooks are already open you simply refer to them by name e.g.

```
Workbooks("formini1.xlsm")
```

If they are not open then you need to open them first with

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C://project/database/formini1.xlsm") ' though need to verify this if you are using a mac
```

and then refer to

```
Set RangeTabel = wb.Sheets("Sheet3").[A1].CurrentRegion
```

If you are using Windows I would expect a path that looks more like

```
"C:\TopFolder\NextFolder"
```

See here for help with Mac filepaths and getting files:

https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac015.htm

https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/section3.htm

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520898/how-to-open-a-workbook-from-excel-16-with-vba-on-mac) it would suggest for Mac Excel 2016 the fully qualified path inside the `Open` method is needed e.g.

```
"/Users/User/Documents/FileName.xlsm"
```

Here is a test using Windows and the [IsFileOpen](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/291295/macro-code-to-check-whether-a-file-is-already-open) function from the link I gave:

```
Sub Test

    If Not IsFileOpen("C:\TopFolder\NextFolder\FileName.xlsx") Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\TopFolder\NextFolder\FileName.xlsx")
    End If

End Sub


Function IsFileOpen(filename As String)
    Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer

    On Error Resume Next   ' Turn error checking off.
    filenum = FreeFile()   ' Get a free file number.
    ' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
    Open filename For Input Lock Read As #filenum
    Close filenum          ' Close the file.
    errnum = Err           ' Save the error number that occurred.
    On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking back on.

    ' Check to see which error occurred.
    Select Case errnum

        ' No error occurred.
        ' File is NOT already open by another user.
        Case 0
         IsFileOpen = False

        ' Error number for "Permission Denied."
        ' File is already opened by another user.
        Case 70
            IsFileOpen = True

        ' Another error occurred.
        Case Else
            Error errnum
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. Its work. But when I try next search. It said formini1.xlsm is already open. How to make it isn't always reopening the formini1.xlsm?

Comment: Are you using a mac?

Comment: No sir, I use Windows and Ms.Office 2010. Hows?

Comment: Could try the freefile function https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/291295/macro-code-to-check-whether-a-file-is-already-open

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot sir. Btw, I want to ask. Is it possible I use the code without must/always open the file (formini1.xlsm), cause of in real implementation, source file (formini1.xlsm) not must always being opened.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a helper function to set a workbook given its path ad name (explanations in comments):

```
Function GetWorkbook(wbPath As String, wbName As String) As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetWorkbook = Workbooks(wbName) 'try getting wanted workbook between already opened ones
    If GetWorkbook Is Nothing Then Set GetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(wbPath & "\" & wbName) 'if unsuccesfully then open it
End Function
```

that you could use in your code as follows:

```
Set RangeTabel = GetWorkbook("C:\\project\database", "formini1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet3").[A1].CurrentRegion
```

of course you could add more code to handle other possible errors, like:

- not existing workbook with given name or path (maybe caused to some mistyping)
- not existence of wanted sheet in wanted workbook (again, maybe some typos...)